# How to toggle class in vue js of a specific item in v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can i toggle by btn specific div from list of items , which one i got from json and display using v-for ?

I am understand that i can`t just set v-if to div and  add to vue data  , but in this case it fill open and close all divs

```
 <div class="about" v-if="list">
                  <div class="dat"  v-for="data in item.items_situation" :key="data.a">
                        {{data.doc_valid_through}}
                        {{data.document_type}}
                        {{data.item_nr_full}}
                        {{data.item_text}}
                </div>
                <div class="situation-btn">
                    <input class="situatuin-btn" type="submit" value="Подбробнее" v-on:click="hide">
                </div>
            </div>
```

When i click the button i want to toggle one div not all

Comment: share code snippet ?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to achieve this, I'll provide one for you.

1. Map your JSON array in `data` by adding `visible` property for every item.
2. Add button inside loop (so its attached for every item) and make `visible = false` by clicking it.
3. Display filtered results (`visible === true` only)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  data: {
    items: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", id: 1 },
      { text: "Learn Vue", id: 2 },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", id: 3 },
      { text: "Build something awesome", id: 4 }
    ].map(item => ({...item, visible: true})),
    
    hiddenItems: []
  },
  
  
  computed: {
    visibleItems() {
      return this.items.filter(item => item.visible)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="dat" v-for="item in visibleItems" :key="item.id">
    {{item.text}}
    <button v-on:click.prevent="item.visible = false">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use v-bind:class to dynamically add class to elements. Code should be like this:

```
<div class="about" v-if="list">
    <div v-for="data in items" v-bind:class="{hide: data.isHidden}" :key="data.key">
        Something
    </div>
    <div class="situation-btn">
        <input class="situatuin-btn" type="submit" value="Подбробнее" v-on:click="hide">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in `hide`

```
hide(){
    this.items[i].isHidden = true
}
```

The `data.isHidden` property decides whether an element in list should have `hide` class.
See also [Class and Style Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html).

-------Edited-------

I have posted an example [here](https://codepen.io/semperia/pen/YoyERK)

Comment: How it supposed to call exactly for instance second div ? When should i define [i] , can you describe a little bit more ?

Comment: @Bravis Well `i` is just the index of element in list to be hidden, so if you want the second to hide you just need to change it to `this.data.items[1].isHidden = true`. And as there is no style applied to class `hide` you'll need to write CSS for this class yourself like `.hide{ display: none; }`.

Comment: i dont know , it does`not work , event this data.isHidden , how it supposed to work ? i should have this data in my Json , i dont

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake and i have edited my answer. It should be `this.items[i].isHidden` not `this.data.items[i].isHidden`